# Can i run grep from cPanel without SSH?

Tags: linux, grep, cpanel

I need to search a large amount of files on my hosting that runs cPanel.

They don't have SSH, is there a way I can run grep in any other way to search my files for a certain piece of text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
  $command = "grep -ri 'abcdef' ./*";
  $output = shell_exec($command);
  echo "$output";
  echo "Grep job over.";
?>
```

Change to suit your required grep search.

Save as `grep.php`. Then upload to root directory and visit the URL

```
http://Your Site/grep.php
```

Comment: It is confusing when you provide solutions that span multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `grep` command without shell. First you need to check function is enable `shell_exec` enable in `php.ini` then you can use.